# Root to set a battery limit and unroot again?

Tags: root-access, battery-life, unrooting, google-pixel-2

I dont have any practical experience with rooting my phone. There is one thing that's been bugging me for a very long time: I need to be able to set a charging limit on my Pixel 2 since I dont feel like replacing the battery soon and destroying the water resistance.

My question is: if I root and set a charging limit and unroot again, will this setting be erased? As I said, I am not too familiar with the risks of having my OS more vulnerable towards viruses, thus the only thing I want to do is to set the battery charging limit and then just go back to unroot.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I can help you (hopefully) retain the things you achieve with root after un-rooting. Do you know the steps to set charging limit and root, unroot your device?

Answer (score 2):

Setting a charging limit is not persistent. Therefore the call has to be made (with root permissions) at least once after every reboot.

Rooting/unrooting requires at least a reboot. Therefore you can't "temporarily root" your device and set a charging limit.

If your device does not provide something like an intelligent battery charging optimization the only alternative is to use a battery charging notification app.

There are a lot if battery charging notification apps on Play Store. One example is [Battery Full Charge Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps.syrupy.fullbatterychargealarm)  which can be configured to notify at a specific charging level.

Comment: I know, AccuBattery also has that feature. I wish it was something you could set to happen automatically without having to root your device. My other idea was to use Tasker and get a smart plug but the sheer thought of having to buy additional devices is kind of frustrating.